# Use while loop to pause javascript while waiting for AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to wait for an ajax response before continuing the code, otherwise a variable (data) is undefined. It would be difficult to rewrite the code to put the next portion all within its own function.

The following while loop just crashes the browser, any ideas to do something similar to this, but that works?

```
name = getName(id);

while (name == null || name == undefined) {
    //wait for response before continuing
} 
...
```

Comment: Did you search the `async` option for AJAX request?

Comment: Do NOT do that! It will freeze the browser!

Comment: Do you know `XMLHTTPRequest` does let you choose async or sync?

Comment: FYI, `name == null` is exactly the same as `name == null || name == undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change ajax to work sync and not async:

[JQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Set the async property to false. The default is true.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  async: false,
  success: function(result) { // it will get here synced and not asynced!!! },
  ...........
});
```

BTW, It's not recomended to work that way since your performing a blocking operation. Thats the reason it returns a promise.

Comment: `async: false` is depreciated, and no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

You must use callback after response from backend

e.g jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/url',
    success : function(response){
           //your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of waiting for the return and not wanting to write the code into the callback. (Though I'm not sure if that sounds like a good requirement)

Comment: I don't recommend use while loop to check when return response from server. Callback is the best way to check is data returned. 

You can use setInterval() to check e.g. after every second response

Comment: Agree on not recommending `while`, but Amiros' answer shows how it can be done without